# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < runtime.4501af5c35d1125f6901.js:1 upon running IISnode

Tags: node.js, iis, iisnode

**Root directory inside iisnode**
[image]

**inside client directory**
[image]

```
<!doctype html>
     <html lang="en">
    <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title>ANSYS Licensing Portal</title>
       <base href="/node/">
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
       <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="" crossorigin="anonymous">
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.82aa555aa62ae3bd79d8.css"></head>
    <body>
       <style>...</style>
        <app-root>
                <div class="top-container">
            <mat-toolbar class="mat-elevation-z2 toptoolbar">
                <div class="divlogo">
                    <img class="logoloading" src="" alt="Portal Logo">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="loading"> Portal Loading...</p>
                </div>
                <span class="app-toolbar-filler"></span>
            </mat-toolbar>
            </div>
        </app-root>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="runtime.4501af5c35d1125f6901.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.c466c90744ce632ac8b9.js">
      </script><script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.2491a780f92813f20e72.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="main.c1b82e811a8fb7c4cdaf.js"> </script></body>
     </html>
```

I am running iisnode. I deployed the project into iisnode as shown in question link. I have enabled directory browsing. I have shown web.config,app.js and here I will post index.js as well.

I have static contents in client directory. I have node.js contents in server directory. Please note I have only one web.config for entire, I don't web.config per directory, Is this ok?

Snapshot of error
[image]

[image]

Comment: The error message says that instead of serving JS, you are serving the HTML file. You can look at build folder and verify that JS is really JS. Therefore, the problem is with how your web server is configured. You should make sure runtime.4501af5c35d1125f6901.js really serves the JS file, and not something else.you could refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34105183/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-in-nodejs) solution.

Comment: HI,I came across the same problem and solved by following below link https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/tips-for-running-an-angular-app-in-iis/

Comment: Thanks KCN I will try this out